# Type '{ data: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm having errors here in data property

```
interface Props {
  params: { slug: string };
}

const Page = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const data: any = await getPage(params.slug);

  // responsible for dynamically rendering the appropriate organism (e.g., ContactUs or AboutUs etc...) within the PageComponent based on the dynamic route parameter.
  const PageComponent = dynamic(() =>
    import(`@/components/organisms/${data.slug}`).then(
      (module) => module.default
    )
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <PageComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7uEn.png)
Type '{ data: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
(property) data: any

Data works and logs perfectly fine in my component
contact-us component

```
interface Props {
  data: any;
}

export default function ContactUs({ data }: Props) {
  console.log(data);
  return <div>{}</div>;
}
```

How do I deal with the type error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue here is because NextJS doesn't know what type you're importing so it doesn't know what the props type should be.

The solution should be something like this:

```js
interface Props {
  params: { slug: string };
}

const Page = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const data: any = await getPage(params.slug);

  // responsible for dynamically rendering the appropriate organism (e.g., ContactUs or AboutUs etc...) within the PageComponent based on the dynamic route parameter.
  const PageComponent = dynamic<{data: any}>(() =>
    import(`@/components/organisms/${data.slug}`).then(
      (module) => module.default
    )
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <PageComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

note the <{data: any}> on the dynamic call